# Compare document.getElementsByClassName().innerHTML with int

Tags: javascript, if-statement, innerhtml, parseint, getelementsbyclassname

I have the given code:

```
function fill_random() {
let field = document.getElementsByClassName("field")
let random
for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        random = Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 9)
        if (check(random))
            field[j + (i * 9)].innerHTML = `${random}`
        else
            j--
    }
}
}

function check(random) {
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if (parseInt(document.getElementsByClassName("field")[j + (i * 9)].innerHTML) === random) {
            console.log("Match!")
            return false
        }
    }
}
return true
}
```

random is a let filled with

```
Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 9)
```

When I try to execute it, the page won't load. When I try without parseInt() the page and everything else works but the if-condition never matches.
Obviously because I cant compare the innterHTML to an int.

So how to correctly cast the innerHTML to an int?

EDIT
Added more code as requested in the comments.
By "page won't load" I mean the page is loading forever. After few seconds the browser (Chrome latest version, no addons) asks me to leave the page or wait.
In the state of waiting it wont let me open developer tools.

The output of

```
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("field")[j + (i * 9)].innerHTML)
```

gives a Number from 1 to 9 as string. Which is what I expect. Maybe my problem is not the parseInt() function but something else I can't figure out.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. Your `parseInt` call looks mostly fine.

Comment: Sounds like there's a console error you've overlooked occurring on page load in the `parseInt` case.

Comment: Maybe there is no such element.  Did you mean `(i * 3)` perhaps?

Comment: "the page won't load". I highly doubt this code would stop a page from loading. Please show how the function is called. Please also open your Developer Tools console and report any errors you see.

Comment: I updated the main post with more information.

Comment: "Obviously because I cant compare the innterHTML to an int." - Oh yes you can, say innerHTML = "9" will compare \ evaluate to `true`  with integer of the value 9;  `"9" == 9 > true`.

Comment: It must be something else then. Anyhow the if-condition is never true.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problems with the parseInt function, you could remove it and use a loose equality comparison (`==` instead of `===`).

```
function check(random) {
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if (document.getElementsByClassName("field")[j + (i * 9)].innerHTML == random) {
            console.log("Match!")
            return false
        }
    }
}
return true
}
```

Comment: Tried that. It doesn't help. I added more code above.